# SQL Server merge statement produces assertion error in SQL Server 2017 even with latest service pack

Tags: sql-server, merge, assertion

I have installed the latest service pack for SQL Server 2017 but still, the assertion error occurs. The error seemly to be inconsistent.

Comment: Are you able to share the query and explain entities around it with your objective?

Comment: It would be helpful to share the exact code and the exact error. I never use MERGE. Instead I use seperate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Comment: It is quite possible your statement is the one that's inconsistent; parallelism and timing issues can cause the error to appear only sporadically. `MERGE` is notoriously difficult to use well; for simple scenarios it's overkill and for complicated scenarios it's hard to ensure you abide by its rules of determinism (and that's after the bugs in the implementation).

Comment: The error message is: 3624(Severity 20). This is an internal SQL Server error called an "assertion failure" that is typically a software bug, though it could indicate internal data corruption. This is oftentimes addressed via a SQL Server service pack or patch.